# How can I have Rails form with data-remote: true but submit via button regularly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autosave, stimulusjs

I have a Rails form as shown below.  What I'm attempting to do is have it autosave on keypress; however, if the user clicks "Submit" it will save as it normally would.  Currently as shown below clicking the "Submit" button will just execute the ajax save via "Rails.fire"

**Example Form:**

```
<%= form_with(model: [player, report], id: "#{dom_id(report)}_form", class: "contents", data: { controller: "autosave", "autosave-target": "form", action: "ajax:success->autosave#success ajax:error->autosave#error", remote: "true"}) do |form| %>

  <%= form.text_field :name, { class: "form-text-field", data: { action: "keyup->autosave#save" } } %>

  <%= form.submit class: "px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md shadow-sm text-white bg-purple-600 hover:bg-purple-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-purple-500" %>

<% end %>
```

**Stimulus Controller**

```
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus'
import Rails from '@rails/ujs'

Rails.start()

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['form', 'status']

  connect() {
    this.timeout = null
    this.duration = this.data.get('duration') || 1000
    console.log("Autosave enabled.")
  }

  save() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.statusTarget.textContent = 'Saving...'
      Rails.fire(this.formTarget, 'submit')
    }, this.duration)
  }

  success() {
    var date = new Date(); 
    
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    
    var dateString = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + date.getSeconds() + ' ' + ampm;

    this.setStatus("Last autosaved at " + date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth()+1)  + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " @ " + dateString.replace(/(^|\D)(\d)(?!\d)/g, '$10$2'))
  }

  error() {
    this.setStatus('Unable to Autosave!')
  }

  setStatus(message) {
    this.statusTarget.textContent = message
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deciding to change my button to look like the following ...

**Notice the "onclick"**

```
<%= form.submit onclick: "this.form.submit();", class: "px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md shadow-sm text-white bg-purple-600 hover:bg-purple-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-purple-500" %>
```